# looking for software to visualise and edit this image turned to text

Tags: data-visualization

I bought a stage lightning laser that has a Bluetooth app paired with it from China.

The app is not really user-friendly, is only for android and doesn't use any file formats that I know of. For example, for pattern it says it's a .pa file etc.
But when I open the image in something like notepad it gives a string of code using x and y coordinates so I was wondering if any of you know any software that might visualise it and even better also edit this preferably on a Windows computer. I'll post the code below

> [{"index":0,"startColor":-65536,"endColor":-131071,"isClosed":true,"textContext":-131071,"curGrapType":"FONT","centerPoint":{"centerPointX":0.5138888888888888,"centerPointY":0.43333333333333335},"curGrapRect":{"left":0.22314814814814815,"top":0.39814814814814814,"right":0.8046296296296296,"bottom":0.4685185185185185},"drawGrapPointList":[{"x":0.2722222222222222,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-65536,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.25462962962962965,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-848896,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.28425925925925927,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-1697536,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.30185185185185187,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-2546176,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.2722222222222222,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-3394816,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.33425925925925926,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-4243456,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.2935185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-5092096,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.22314814814814815,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-5940736,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.26296296296296295,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-6789376,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.33425925925925926,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-7638016,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.33425925925925926,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-8486656,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.3990740740740741,"y":0.4222222222222222,"color":-9335296,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.4444444444444444,"y":0.42314814814814816,"color":-10183936,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.4324074074074074,"y":0.44351851851851853,"color":-11032576,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.387037037037037,"y":0.4425925925925926,"color":-11881216,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.3990740740740741,"y":0.4222222222222222,"color":-12729856,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.37962962962962965,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-13578496,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.42962962962962964,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-14427136,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.4185185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-15275776,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.34814814814814815,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-16124416,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.38796296296296295,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-16712956,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.45925925925925926,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-16716271,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.44722222222222224,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-16719586,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.3972222222222222,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-16722901,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.37962962962962965,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-16726216,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.37962962962962965,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-16729531,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5435185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-16732846,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.47314814814814815,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-16736161,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.512962962962963,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-16739476,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5333333333333333,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-16742791,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5046296296296297,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-16746106,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5546296296296296,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-16749421,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5435185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-16752736,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5435185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-16756051,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6175925925925926,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-16759366,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-16762681,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6296296296296297,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-16765996,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6472222222222223,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-16769311,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6175925925925926,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-16772626,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6796296296296296,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-16775941,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6388888888888888,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-16187146,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.5685185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-15335191,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6083333333333333,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-14483236,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6796296296296296,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-13631281,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6796296296296296,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-12779326,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7444444444444445,"y":0.4222222222222222,"color":-11927371,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7898148148148149,"y":0.42314814814814816,"color":-11075416,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7777777777777778,"y":0.44351851851851853,"color":-10223461,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7324074074074074,"y":0.4425925925925926,"color":-9371506,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7444444444444445,"y":0.4222222222222222,"color":-8519551,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.725,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-7667596,"startPoint":true,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.775,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-6815641,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7638888888888888,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-5963686,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.6935185185185185,"y":0.4685185185185185,"color":-5111731,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7333333333333333,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-4259776,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.8046296296296296,"y":0.39814814814814814,"color":-3407821,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7925925925925926,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-2555866,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.7425925925925926,"y":0.41759259259259257,"color":-1703911,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.725,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-851956,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false},{"x":0.725,"y":0.44814814814814813,"color":-131071,"startPoint":false,"originalPoint":false}]}]

Comment: I havent looked into SVG formats, but it does look similar.  Try renaming it to xxx.svg and then click on it